Automate PowerShell Script
How I can Excute a powershell script when a devices are in battery mode? this powershell script will send a email with the hostname when the battery Estimated Charge Remaining has for example 30%.
I am working with the cmdlet Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery, and I am expecting is trigger the script automaticaly when the battery Estimated Charge Remaining has for example 30%.

using Task Scheduler to manage the trigger of the script is more likely what you need

Thanks @sirtao I was thinking in that, but this Task Scheduler must be running since the device is log in and run it in few minutes interval?

Task Scheduler is always running. There are multiple options, like get it run the script every X minutes, with the script checking the battery and then, if necessary, sending the mail. Or having Task Scheduler itself activating at a certain thresold. No idea what's the event to check for it tho'
